# Why Wordpress w/ Nginx Multisite Only Lets Admin Upload ZIP Plugins But Not Themes?

Tags: multisite, themes, nginx

Wordpress 3.3 multisite / NginX. I can upload all the plugins I want in ZIP format but I cant upload a zipped theme and it can't be over 2megs in size. I cant find where these moronic rule are located. Is there a way to just use the SFTP? At this point I will take my chances with hackers, but life with ssh alone is just miserable hell. Please give me a hint as to how do i get a theme onto the server in a zip file from my pc. thank you.

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/nginx.log info;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    server_tokens off;
    include mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    index index.php index.htm index.html redirect.php;

    #Gzip
    gzip  on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6].(?!.*SV1)";
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    #FastCGI
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_ignore_client_abort on;
    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 120;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;

    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/s;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

Comment: Server configuration questions are off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 1):

On your site's configuration file, please put the following code...

```
client_max_body_size 16M;
```

Please change the number 16M to any other value that suits your theme size. By default it is 2M (short for 2MB).